# Multidimensional Array MySQLi --> PHP --> JSON --> HighCharts

Tags: php, mysql, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a JSON array from a MySQL database full of sensor values. I am trying to create a multidimensional array from the MySQL results so one query will do all, an thus hopefully reduce server load...?

I want to use the results in highcharts to plot the results from multiple sensor nodes with multiple sensors. I want to plot the results with a time axis.

First I am not sure if a large array with all my data is the correct approach or if multiple smaller arrays are better, any comments welcome on that subject. What I was looking help in was creating a JSON array.

What I have so far is:

```
<?php
require_once 'db_login.php'; //get login details for the database

$db_server = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database)or die('There was a problem connecting to the database');

$query = "
SELECT sensorID,timeStamp,theDate,theDay,theHour,avgTemp,avgHumidity,avgLight,avgOccupied
FROM
(
  select
    `sensor_id` AS sensorID,
    `value_date` AS timeStamp,
    DAY(`value_date`) AS theDate,
    DAYNAME(`value_date`) AS theDay,
    HOUR(`value_date`) AS theHour, 
    AVG(`value_temp`) AS avgTemp,
    AVG(`value_humidity`) AS avgHumidity,
    AVG(`value_light`) AS avgLight,
    AVG(`value_PIR`) AS avgOccupied
  FROM sensor_value
  WHERE `value_date` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  AND `value_date` < NOW()
  GROUP BY sensorID,theDate,theHour
) s
GROUP BY sensorID,theDate,theHour; 
";

$result = $db_server->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($sensorID, $timeStamp, $theDate, $theDay, $theHour, $avgTemp, $avgHumidity, $avgLight, $avgOccupied);
while ($result->fetch()) 
{
//if($theHour<1) $theHour=0.000001;

//    $data[$sensorID][$theDate][$theDay][$theHour] = array(
//      "Temp" => $avgTemp,
//      "Humidity" => $avgHumidity,
//      "Light" => $avgLight,
//      "Occupied" => $avgOccupied
//    );


      $data[]['ID'] = array(
                "SensorID" => $sensorID,
                "DateID" => array(
                  "Date" => $theDate,
                  "Day" => $theDay,
                  "HourID" => array(
                    "Hour" => $theHour,
                    "Results" => array(
                      "Temp" => $avgTemp,
                      "Humidity" => $avgHumidity,
                      "Light" => $avgLight,
                      "Occupied" => $avgOccupied
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        );

    );

}

header("content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

$db_server->close();
?>
```

Which gives me:

```
[
    {
        "ID": {
            "SensorID": 123456789012,
            "DateID": {
                "Date": 16,
                "Day": "Sunday",
                "HourID": {
                    "Hour": 15,
                    "Results": {
                        "Temp": "21.000000",
                        "Humidity": "66.600000",
                        "Light": "620.6667",
                        "Occupied": "0.0000"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "ID": {
            "SensorID": 123456789012,
            "DateID": {
                "Date": 16,
                "Day": "Sunday",
                "HourID": {
                    "Hour": 16,
                    "Results": {
                        "Temp": "21.282203",
                        "Humidity": "66.494915",
                        "Light": "668.0763",
                        "Occupied": "0.1441"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
..........etc.
]
```

How can I nest the results under the same sensor, then under the same day?

I code that I started with:

```
while ($result->fetch()) 
{
    $data[$sensorID][$theDate][$theDay][$theHour] = array(
      "Temp" => $avgTemp,
      "Humidity" => $avgHumidity,
      "Light" => $avgLight,
      "Occupied" => $avgOccupied
    );
}
```

Had the sort of the correct nesting I wanted but no keys, so I found it hard to actually use the results. Snip-it of above code:

```
{
    "123456789012": {
        "16": {
            "Sunday": {
                "16": {
                    "Temp": "21.314019",
                    "Humidity": "66.471028",
                    "Light": "673.0561",
                    "Occupied": "0.1402"
                },
                "17": {
                    "Temp": "21.927350",
                    "Humidity": "63.827350",
                    "Light": "649.4188",
                    "Occupied": "0.0684"
                },
                "18": {
                    "Temp": "22.291525",
                    "Humidity": "63.710169",
                    "Light": "615.2712",
                    "Occupied": "0.0339"
                },
                "19": {
                    "Temp": "21.324576",
                    "Humidity": "64.744068",
                    "Light": "468.7542",
                    "Occupied": "0.0085"
                },
                "20": {
                    "Temp": "20.801709",
                    "Humidity": "67.853846",
                    "Light": "401.1197",
                    "Occupied": "0.0000"
                },
                "21": {
                    "Temp": "20.383051",
                    "Humidity": "68.610169",
                    "Light": "183.9407",
                    "Occupied": "0.0000"
                },
                "22": {
                    "Temp": "20.104237",
                    "Humidity": "69.753390",
                    "Light": "16.9068",
                    "Occupied": "0.0000"
                },
                "23": {
                    "Temp": "19.939831",
                    "Humidity": "70.229661",
                    "Light": "133.5678",
                    "Occupied": "0.0000"
                }
            }
        },
        "17": {
            "Monday": [
                {
                    "Temp": "19.728205",
                    "Humidity": "70.501709",
                    "Light": "8.0000",
                    "Occupied": "0.0000"
                },
    ......etc....
    ]
```

I have tried adding a foreach loop to nest the data, but could not construct a suitable function that worked...

Can anyone help with creating this array or am I making life hard for myself? Should I move to multiple queries?

**EDITED**
Desired output:

```
[
    {
        "ID": {
            "SensorID": 123456789012,
            "DateID": {
                "Date": 16,
                "Day": "Sunday",
                "HourID": {
                    "Hour": 17,
                    "Results": {
                        "Temp": "21.965217",
                        "Humidity": "62.708696",
                        "Light": "649.1449",
                        "Occupied": "0.0725"
                    }
                    "Hour": 18,
                    "Results": {
                        "Temp": "22.291525",
                        "Humidity": "63.710169",
                        "Light": "615.2712",
                        "Occupied": "0.0339"
                    }
                    "Hour": 19,
                    "Results": {
                        "Temp": "21.324576",
                        "Humidity": "64.744068",
                        "Light": "468.7542",
                        "Occupied": "0.0085"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
....etc....
]
```

Comment: what structure do you want?

Comment: The same as the first output listed, but I don't want the sensor ID repeated or the day repeated.

Comment: eh...it looks like you've done that.

Comment: But How do a get the correct nesting with the desired Keys?

Comment: you cant have more than 1 "Hour" key per object.

Comment: Well the code in the middle of the post which I said I started with, is there a way of adding keys to the different layers in it? so I parse it?